# Let a user to run a command as a member of a group he does not belong to, using `sudoers`

Tags: linux, debian, sudo, acl, sudoers

How can I let a user **U** to run a command **/usr/bin/C** as a member of a group **G** (while he does not belong to the group **G**), using sudoers on Debian Wheezy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

U = an user
G = a group to which user doesn't belong
C = a command
M = the machine

if you've got the line:

```
U M=:G C
```

so if you want user 'test' launch command 'touch' as group 'whatever' on machine 'aserver' you should add:

```
test aserver=(:whatever) /usr/bin/touch
```

in sudoers, then you'll be able to launch touch as group whatever via:

```
sudo -g whatever touch mytestfile
```

Comment: In my case command C is /usr/bin/nautilus-sendto which is normally called by a user through GUI (Nautilus), in order for things to remain transparent for the user I have to avoid using command line (`sudo -g whatever touch mytestfile`). So is there a way to make it transparent?

Comment: @user1876484 - should this be `U M=:G C` and `test aserver=:whatever /usr/bin/touch` or `U M=(:G) C` and `test aserver=(:whatever) /usr/bin/touch`?

Comment: the set should be:

user machine=(:group) command

Comment: @user1876484 - what about my first comment - how to make it Gnome-transparent. I thought to substitute the original /usr/bin/nautilus-sendto with a bash script that will have `sudo -g floppy /usr/bin/nautilus-sendto.original $1` inside. But the problem is sudo wants to check the password of user - is there a way to force sudo to run the program without asking for password? Or maybe you have another workaround to make this Gnome-transparent?

Comment: Wops, sorry: just saw your comment.
NOPASSWD: flag before command alias should do the job:


User Machine=(:Group) NOPASSWD: Command